# Read json file and append a particular array to outer scope list - javascript - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
var dir = require('node-dir');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var root_directory = "C:/ProgramData/XXX/YYY/Resources/LocalLibrary";



function getitems(res, fileHandler){
    dir.files(root_directory, function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        fileHandler(res, files);    
    });
};

function fileHandler(res, files) {
    var finaldependency = [];
    files.forEach(function (fileName) {
        if (path.extname(fileName) === '.Item') {
            var singleObj = {};
            singleObj['key'] = fileName;
            var content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(fileName), "utf8");
            var json = JSON.parse(content);
            singleObj['value'] = json.References;
            finaldependency.push(singleObj);
        }
    });
    res.json(finaldependency);
}


module.exports = function(app) {

    // api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // get all items
    app.get('/api/item', function(req, res) {

        // use mongoose to get all items in the database
        getitems(res, fileHandler);
    });
```

Steps Involved:
1.When receive a request process all the files present in the root_directory(it contains many nested subdirectories)
2. get the list of all the files with the help of node-dir module
3. pass the file list to a asynchronous fileHandler

My question ? I am doing a synchronous blocking style of file Handling(fs.readfileSync) !!!
and append the data as a key-value pair to the outer scope list finaldependency

Is this a right approach ?? or is there any optimized approach of doing this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fileHandler` function might take long time hence it can block client request. Server performance in terms of request processing might get worse with increasing client request.

You can try executing the `forEach` loop in [process.nextTick](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick.).

Comment: My doubt is whether i can implement the above code in non-blocking manner i.e without using readFileSync, and to use asynchronous method readFile for better performance ????

Comment: Yes, you can.
Have a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to read all your file in parallel and wait for the task to be completed.

Having said that, you can also use  process.nextTick and readFileSync to make your application unblocking.

Comment: Oh Cool Akash thanks  I got the point :) Once Again thanks a lot